# Aggregate multiple calls then separate result with Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Currently I have many concurrent identical calls to my backend, differing only on an ID field:

```
getData(1).then(...) // Each from a React component in a UI framework, so difficult to aggregate here
getData(2).then(...)
getData(3).then(...)

// creates n HTTP requests... inefficient
function getData(id: number): Promise<Data> {
  return backend.getData(id);
}
```

This is wasteful as I make more calls. I'd like to keep my `getData()` calls, but then aggregate them into a single `getDatas()` call to my backend, then return all the results to the callers. I have more control over my backend than the UI framework, so I can easily add a `getDatas()` call on it. **The question is how to "mux" the JS calls into one backend call, the "demux" the result into the caller's promises.**

```
const cache = Map<number, Promise<Data>>()
let requestedIds = []
let timeout = null;

// creates just 1 http request (per 100ms)... efficient!
function getData(id: number): Promise<Data> {
  if (cache.has(id)) {
    return cache;
  }
  
  requestedIds.push(id)
  if (timeout == null) {
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      backend.getDatas(requestedIds).then((datas: Data[]) => {
        // TODO: somehow populate many different promises in cache??? but how?
        requestedIds = []
        timeout = null
      }
    }, 100)
  }
  return ???
}
```

In Java I would create a `Map<int, CompletableFuture>` and upon finishing my backend request, I would look up the CompletableFuture and call `complete(data)` on it. But I think in JS `Promise`s can't be created without an explicit result being passed in.

Can I do this in JS with Promises?

Comment: isn't it a backend solution to solve? if it's the same call with differing Ids, can all data for given IDs be sent over one HTTP call?

Comment: Yes, I can create a single backend call. I've edited my post to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution:

```
interface PromiseContainer {
    resolve;
    reject;
}

const requests: Map<number, PromiseContainer<Data>> = new Map();
let timeout: number | null = null;
function getData(id: number) {
  const promise = new Promise<Data>((resolve, reject) => requests.set(id, { resolve, reject }))
  if (timeout == null) {
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      backend.getDatas([...requests.keys()]).then(datas => {
        for (let [id, data] of Object.entries(datas)) {
          requests.get(Number(id)).resolve(data)
          requests.delete(Number(id))
        }
      }).catch(e => {
        Object.values(requests).map(promise => promise.reject(e))
      })
      timeout = null
    }, 100)
  }
  return promise;
}
```

The key was figuring out I could extract the `(resolve, reject)` from a promise, store them, then retrieve and call them later.

Comment: Saving and distributing the promise resolution functions is indeed the key to the solution, but I have the urge to rewrite this a little bit, reusing the cache structure for both promises and the resolved data.  Also, can you explain the timeout?  Is that hoping to allow multiple individual requests to pile up?  That can be improved, too.  I don't see any second (delay in ms) param passed.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the timeout ms - yes, the timeout is meant as a buffer; this will collect 100ms of requests then batch them all at once. Definitely open for improvements if you want to edit this or create your own answer!

Comment: I've posted a sort of outline (it might run, but of course it's untested) for how I'd divide up the logic and reuse the promises themselves as the result-holding objects in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

A little unclear on what your end goal looks like. I imagine you could loop through your calls as needed; Perhaps something like:

```
for (let x in cache){
   if (x.has(id))
      return x;
   } 

//OR

for (let x=0; x<id.length;x++){
  getData(id[x])
}
```

Might work. You may be able to add a timing method into the mix if needed.

Not sure what your backend consists of, but I do know GraphQL is a good system for making multiple calls.

It may be ultimately better  to handle them all in one request, rather than multiple calls.

Answer (score 1):

The cache can be a regular object mapping ids to promise resolution functions and the promise to which they belong.

```
// cache maps ids to { resolve, reject, promise, requested }
// resolve and reject belong to the promise, requested is a bool for bookkeeping
const cache = {};
```

You might need to fire only once, but here I suggest setInterval to regularly check the cache for unresolved requests:

```
// keep the return value, and stop polling with clearInterval()
// if you really only need one batch, change setInterval to setTimeout
function startGetBatch() {
  return setInterval(getBatch, 100);
}
```

The business logic calls only `getData()` which just hands out (and caches) promises, like this:

```
function getData(id) {
  if (cache[id]) return cache[id].promise;
  cache[id] = {};
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Object.assign(cache[id], { resolve, reject });
  });
  cache[id].promise = promise;
  cache[id].requested = false;
  return cache[id].promise;
}
```

By saving the promise along with the resolver and rejecter, we're also implementing the cache, since the resolved promise will provide the thing it resolved to via its then() method.

`getBatch()` asks the server in a batch for the not-yet-requested `getData()` ids, and invokes the corresponding resolve/reject functions:

```
function getBatch() {
  // for any
  const ids = [];
  Object.keys(cache).forEach(id => {
    if (!cache[id].requested) {
      cache[id].requested = true;
      ids.push(id);
    }
  });
  return backend.getDatas(ids).then(datas => {
    Object.keys(datas).forEach(id => {
      cache[id].resolve(datas[id]);
    })
  }).catch(error => {
    Object.keys(datas).forEach(id => {
      cache[id].reject(error);
      delete cache[id]; // so we can retry
    })
  })
}
```

The caller side looks like this:

```
// start polling 
const interval = startGetBatch();

// in the business logic
getData(5).then(result => console.log('the result of 5 is:', result));
getData(6).then(result => console.log('the result of 6 is:', result));

// sometime later...
getData(5).then(result => {
  // if the promise for an id has resolved, then-ing it still works, resolving again to the -- now cached -- result
  console.log('the result of 5 is:', result)
});

// later, whenever we're done 
// (no need for this if you change setInterval to setTimeout)
clearInterval(interval);
```